How to solve constraints issue: Position is ambiguous for UIButton?
I have placed UIButton to right view of textfield. But I see the below warning 
My code for UIButton:
private lazy var myButton : UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    config.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
    button.configuration = config
    button.frame = CGRect(x:   CGFloat(myTextfield.frame.size.width - 16), y:(myTextfield.frame.size.height - 16) / 2, width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(30))
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(passwordButtonImage, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

code for adding it to textfield:
@IBOutlet private weak var mytextField: UITextField  {
    didSet {
       
        mytextField.rightView = myButton
        mytextField.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}


Since you are using the button as the text field's rightView, try setting the button's frame (for the width and height) instead of using a constraint to set the width.

I also tried setting frame but no luck, edited question

Are you sure the warning is about this specific button? Are there any other buttons in your storyboard?

I am sure as I saw this warning while capturing user interface

If you are not using constraints, you should not set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false.

@Sweeper removing  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false solved my issue please post this as answer

It appears that Duncan C already posted that. You should accept his answer :)

I haven't set frame, I just place my button as rightzview of textfield and removed translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false. partially its correct

Removing translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false solved my issue. As I am not giving any constraints manually I don't need this.
